# Not getting expected results using findall in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am new to python(using 2.7.3). I was trying to do web scraping using python but I am ot getting the expected outputs:

```
import urllib
import re
regex='<title>(.+?)<\title>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
dummy="fsdfsdf<title>Test<\title>dsf"
html=urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
text=html.read()
print pattern.findall(text)
print pattern.findall(dummy)
```

while the second print statement is working fine but the first one should print Google but it is giving a blank list.

Comment: Use an html parser, not regex

Comment: Why don't u use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: Using more descriptive variable names is a good practice too when you're looking for people to help you with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing:

```
regex='<title>(.+?)<\title>'
```

to

```
regex='<title>(.+?)</title>'
```

Comment: thanks really a silly error. wasted a lot of hours in reading all whole re package in python documentation but didn't check my regex.

Comment: That's why you use an HTML parser and not regular expressions to parse HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You mistyped the slash:

```
regex='<title>(.+?)<\title>'
```

should be:

```
regex='<title>(.+?)</title>'
```

HTML uses a *forward* slash in closing tags.

That said, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Matching HTML with such expressions get too complicated, too fast.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from. I recommend you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a popular 3rd party library.

BeautifulSoup example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.info().getparam('charset'))
title = soup.find('title').text
```